# Get ListViewItem instead of Item from a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

For my Drag and Drop from ListView to Canvas, I want the objects to get dropped like I picked them up. For example:

I pick up an Item, and my mouse is 50 pixels lower, and 20 pixels right from the top left corner of the ListViewItem. Then I want the item, when I drop it, to be 50 pixels higher and 20 pixels left, so I get the same position relative to when I picked it up. This is my event that gets triggered, when I click onto an Item and start to drag:

```
void StackPanel_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = GetCurrentIndex(e.GetPosition);

        var ListIteminstance = ModuleListView.Items[index] as ListViewItem;
        // Now you got the original object and then do what you want. 

        startPoint = e.GetPosition(ListIteminstance);
    }
```

`ListIteminstance` is null, cause it cannot convert the item to a ListViewItem. Cause of that, I only get the coordinates "0, 0" from the Item, when I drop it, it's from the top left corner, instead of the relative coordinates where I picked it up

`GetCurrentIndex()` gets me the index of the Item I am clicking on. But it is not a ListViewItem, but the object of  type "MyClass", that I store in the list. Now I'm wondering, how I can get the ListViewItem I am clicking on, so that `ListIteminstance` is not null

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var dataObject = ModuleListView.Items[index];
var ListIteminstance = ModuleListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataObject) 
    as ListViewItem;
```

Comment: This still drops the Item at 0, 0 relative to my mouse

Comment: You asked on how to get a reference to the `ListViewItem` container and that's what I answered. Is `ListIteminstance` it still `null`?

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake. I sat on that problem for some hours and forgot to use these coordinates

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn: So where does that leave your question? Are you able to get a reference to the `ListViewItem` using my suggestion?